# How to hide/disable CDT launchbar?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-cdt

I've updated my Eclipse IDE recently and a new launchbar appeared after the CDT update.
I really don't like it, which is why I'm trying to get rid of it. I haven't yet found a way to hide or disable it...

Do you know how I could do this ?
Here's a snapshot of the launchbar : https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/1/15/CDTLaunchBar.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [LaunchBar](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/LaunchBar) (`org.eclipse.launchbar.feature.group`) comes as a dependency of "C/C++ Qt Support" (`org.eclipse.cdt.qt.feature.group`), so you need to either un-install the Qt Support CDT component, or disable the LaunchBar in Eclipse preferences:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The launchbar used to come as a plugin for the CDT, which is probably how you got it, but it was later (in the Mars release) was moved to be a standalone feature - which is probably what @Doug Schaefer refers to.

If you have the new version of the Launch Bar that is installed as a feature, you can go to Help -> About Eclipse and click the "Installation Details" button. In the "Installation Details" under "Installed Software" you should see the "Launch Bar" and be able to uninstall it. Note that if you had the Launch Bar installed previously as a plugin, it will still remain on your system after you have removed the Launch Bar feature.

Regardless if you have the feature version or the plugin version (or both), you can also just hide it using the Eclipse preferences: Run/Debug -> Launching -> Launch Bar, and there would be 2 or 3 check boxes - just uncheck all of them (or just the first actually) and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure how you got it. The LaunchBar isn't part of the CDT. Only the new Arduino CDT uses it.

To remove it, find the org.eclipse.launchbar feature and uninstall it.

Comment: Is the LaunchBar necessary for the Arduino CDT? I've just installed the Arduino stuff into Neon and I find the launchbar aesthetically pretty horrible to be honest (horses for courses and that...). I'd like to get rid of it but can't find any way to uninstall it from within the Eclipse "Installation Details" window; is it safe to just delete the features/org.eclipse.launchbar_2.0.1.blah and features/org/eclipse.launchbar.remote_1.0.1.blah folders?