# How do I remove this launch configurations bar in the toolbar on eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, toolbar

I am trying to setup my eclipse to run some C but there is this long tool in the toolbar which i am not even using and I do not know how to disable it.

Can someone help me please?[image: see in green]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46952856/6505250

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
Help|Install new Software|What is already installed?

and then uninstall the following:

LaunchBar   2.2.2.201811071421  org.eclipse.launchbar.feature.group Eclipse CDT

Comment: In Eclipse 2019-03, I am not allowed to uninstall this (greyed out), but as per the instructions in the link in Gem's answer, deselecting "Enable the Launch Bar" does remove the launch items in Eclipse 2019-03.

Comment: @JohnJefferies comment should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

This is `Window|perspective|customise|Tool Bar Visibility`

Perhaps this is a clue (photon launch bar):

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1095011/

They suggest it is on the launch bar preference page.

Comment: Can't help you there as I don't have those particular boxes. But if you turn them all off, does it go away?

Comment: No, even when I turn them all off, it is still there.

Comment: Found the problem!

Comment: As per the instructions in the link, in Eclipse 2019-03, deselecting "Enable the Launch Bar" does remove the launch items.